# Why is my multi-task-learning model not working?

Tags: pytorch, multiclass-classification, multi-task-learning

I'm writing Python code to predict fetal head circumference using regression and classification together in a single model.

The model will train to classify a fetal head image into a range (e.g., 50–60 mm) representing its circumference.

If you look at the code, you'll notice I calculate the loss for both guessing a circumference value and for classifying the image into a circumference range. (My initial plan was to guess the range based on the output of the circumference the model guesses, but I am still not sure how to implement that, so the current model guesses these separately based on the CNN filters.)

However, I'm not experienced with the MTL model, and for some reason, the loss I get for the classification is always 3.5 and not improving.

[Here is a reference to my GitHub](https://github.com/NitayGitHub/FetalCnsClassification.git)

Data Structure

```
class MultiTaskDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, transform_X = None, transform_value_Y = None):
        self.X_train = glob.glob(train_img + '*HC.png') # Save the path of all the images in the training set
        self.transform_X = transform_X
        self.transform_value_Y = transform_value_Y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X_train)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Extract the image
        img_path = self.X_train[idx]
        image = Image.open(img_path)

        # Extract name, value and class label from the CSV file
        filename = os.path.basename(img_path)
        idx_in_csv = train_csv[train_csv['filename'] == os.path.basename(img_path)].index
        if idx_in_csv.empty:
            raise ValueError(f'No entry in CSV file for image {img_path}')

        idx_in_csv = idx_in_csv.item()
        value = float(train_csv.loc[idx_in_csv, 'head circumference (mm)'])
        class_label = float(train_csv.loc[idx_in_csv, 'head circumference class'])

        if self.transform_X:
            image = self.transform_X(image)

        if self.transform_value_Y:
                value = self.transform_value_Y(value)

        return image, {'filename': filename, 'circumference': value, 'class': class_label}
```

Training Model

```
# Define the shared feature extraction backbone
class SharedBackbone(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1):
        super(SharedBackbone, self).__init__()
        self.shared_backbone = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 64, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),

            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),

            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),

            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.shared_backbone(x)

# Define the multi-task model
class MultiTaskModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shared_backbone, value_head, class_head):
        super(MultiTaskModel, self).__init__()
        self.shared_backbone = shared_backbone
        self.value_head = value_head
        self.class_head = class_head

    def forward(self, x):
        shared_features = self.shared_backbone(x)
        value_output = self.value_head(shared_features)
        class_output = self.class_head(shared_features)
        return value_output, class_output

# Create an instance of the shared backbone
shared_backbone = SharedBackbone()

# Define heads for value prediction and class prediction
value_head = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(627200, 256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(256, 1)
)

class_head = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(627200, 256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(256, num_classes)
)
```

Training Loop

````
#from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
#scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.1)

epochs = 10
train_running_loss_history = []
validation_running_loss_history = []

for e in range(epochs):
    train_running_loss = 0.0
    validation_running_loss = 0.0

    multi_task_model.train()
    # Training loop
    for ith_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(train_loader):
        X_train, y_train = sample_batched
        X_train = X_train.to(device).to(torch.float32)
        y_train_value = y_train['circumference'].to(device).to(torch.float32)
        y_train_class = (y_train['class'] - 4).to(device).to(torch.long)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        value_output, class_output = multi_task_model(X_train)

        print(y_train_class.shape)
        print(class_output.shape)

        # Calculate losses
        loss_value = criterion_value(value_output.squeeze(), y_train_value)
        loss_class = criterion_class(class_output, y_train_class)

        # Combine losses
        total_loss = loss_value + loss_class

        # Backward and optimize
        total_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        train_running_loss += total_loss.item()

        if (ith_batch + 1) % 50 == 0:
            print('Epoch: {}, Batch: {}, Value Loss: {:.4f}, Class Loss: {:.4f}'.format(e + 1, ith_batch, loss_value.item(), loss_class.item()))

    # scheduler.step()

    # Validation loop
    with torch.no_grad():
        multi_task_model.eval()
        for ith_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(validation_loader):
            X_val, y_val = sample_batched
            X_val = X_val.to(device).to(torch.float32)
            y_val_value = y_val['circumference'].to(device).to(torch.float32)
            y_val_class = (y_val['class'] - 4).to(device).to(torch.long)

            value_out, class_out = multi_task_model(X_val)
            circumference_loss = criterion_value(value_out.squeeze(), y_val_value)
            classification_loss = criterion_class(class_out, y_val_class)

            combined_validation_loss = circumference_loss + classification_loss
            validation_running_loss += combined_validation_loss.item()

        print("================================================================================")
        print("Epoch {} completed".format(e + 1))

        train_epoch_loss = train_running_loss / len(train_loader)
        validation_epoch_loss = validation_running_loss / len(validation_loader)

        print("Average train loss is {:.4f}".format(train_epoch_loss))
        print("Average validation loss is {:.4f}".format(validation_epoch_loss))
        print("================================================================================")
        train_running_loss_history.append(train_epoch_loss)
        validation_running_loss_history.append(validation_epoch_loss)

    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```
````